# code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS) when executing C++

Tags: c++, c

I wanted to write a simple programming language that transpiles to C, but I keep getting this error:

**Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)**

I do not understand the error. I dont know where the error is.

My code:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
typedef enum {
    UNDEFINED,
    JUMP,
    LOAD,
    INCREMENT,
    DECREMENT,
    MULTIPLY,
    DIVIDE,
    PRINT,
    PROMPT
} Types;

int errorHandling(const char* errorMessage);
int main() {
    try {
        Types tempTypes;
        char *tempValue;

        std::ifstream f("test.lang");
        if (!f) {
            errorHandling("File not found");
        }
        char *fileName = strtok("test.lang", ".");
        //create output file ending with .c
        char *outputFileName = static_cast<char *>(malloc(strlen(fileName) + 3));
        strcpy(outputFileName, fileName);
        strcat(outputFileName, ".c");
        std::ofstream outputFile(outputFileName);
        if (!outputFile) {
            errorHandling("Output file not found");
        }
        //char *memory[] = {};
        //    int pos = 0;
        outputFile << "#include <stdio.h>\n"
                      "int main() {\n"
                      "\tchar *memory[] = {};\n"
                      "\tint pos = 0;\n";

        //remove all new lines from input file
        std::string fileContent;
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(f, line)) {
            fileContent += line;
        }
        for (auto c: fileContent) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                continue;
            } else if (c == '>') {
                if (tempTypes == UNDEFINED) {
                    tempTypes = JUMP;
                } else {
                    errorHandling("Invalid syntax");
                }
            } else if (c == '<') {
                if (tempTypes == UNDEFINED) {
                    tempTypes = LOAD;
                } else {
                    errorHandling("Invalid syntax");
                }
            } else if (c == '+') {
                if (tempTypes == UNDEFINED) {
                    tempTypes = INCREMENT;
                } else {
                    errorHandling("Invalid syntax");
                }
            } else if (c == '-') {
                if (tempTypes == UNDEFINED) {
                    tempTypes = DECREMENT;
                } else {
                    errorHandling("Invalid syntax");
                }
            } else if (c == '*') {
                if (tempTypes == UNDEFINED) {
                    tempTypes = MULTIPLY;
                } else {
                    errorHandling("Invalid syntax");
                }
            } else if (c == '/') {
                if (tempTypes == UNDEFINED) {
                    tempTypes = DIVIDE;
                } else {
                    errorHandling("Invalid syntax");
                }
            } else if (c == '_') {
                if (tempTypes == UNDEFINED) {
                    tempTypes = PRINT;
                } else {
                    errorHandling("Invalid syntax");
                }
            } else if (c == '?') {
                if (tempTypes == UNDEFINED) {
                    tempTypes = PROMPT;
                } else {
                    errorHandling("Invalid syntax");
                }
            } else if (c == ';') {
                if (tempTypes == UNDEFINED) {
                    errorHandling("Invalid syntax");
                } else if (tempTypes == JUMP) {
                    outputFile << "\tpos = " << tempValue << ";\n";
                } else if (tempTypes == LOAD) {
                    outputFile << "\tpos = " << tempValue << ";\n";
                } else if (tempTypes == INCREMENT) {
                    outputFile << "\t*memory[pos] += " << tempValue << ";\n";
                } else if (tempTypes == DECREMENT) {
                    outputFile << "\t*memory[pos] -= " << tempValue << ";\n";
                } else if (tempTypes == MULTIPLY) {
                    outputFile << "\t*memory[pos] *= " << tempValue << ";\n";
                } else if (tempTypes == DIVIDE) {
                    outputFile << "\t*memory[pos] /= " << tempValue << ";\n";
                } else if (tempTypes == PRINT) {
                    outputFile << "\tprintf(\"%c\", *memory[pos]);\n";
                } else if (tempTypes == PROMPT) {
                    outputFile << "\tscanf(\"%c\", *memory[pos]);\n";
                }
            } else {
                tempValue = &c;
            }

        }
        outputFile << "\treturn 0;\n"
                      "}";
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        errorHandling(e.what());
    }

    return 0;
}

int errorHandling(const char* errorMessage) {
    std::cout << errorMessage << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Would be nice if you could explain the problem or solve it
Im using Macosx, 4 Core cpu, 16 GB ram
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You seem to know about `std::string`, so why don't you use it for *all* your strings? That would make the whole filename-construction a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: As for your problem it might be related to `tempValue`. It seem you can use it while uninitialized. And otherwise it's used as a C-style null-terminated string when it's only pointing to a single `char` variable. And a `char` variable that will end its life each iteration of the loop. So plenty of chances for *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Regarding paths, if your compiler support C++17 then consider [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) instead of strings.

Comment: FYI, the `case` statements of a `switch` work with characters.

Answer (score 2):

Bus Errors are often caused by writing to non-writable memory.

Let's take a hacksaw to the program to isolate the most likely cause:

```cpp
#include <cstring> //added this
int main() {
    char *fileName = strtok("test.lang", ".");
}
```

This is all you should need to force the program to fail. To be honest modern C++ knows this is a bad idea, pointing a non-`const` pointer at constant data, and should refuse to compile, though for legacy reasons some major compilers only report a warning when this is done with string literals. Don't ignore the warnings. They are your first line of defense against logic errors. A compiler error means the program's syntax is wrong. It cannot be translated into an executable program. A compiler warning means the syntax is valid, but the logic looks dodgy and should be inspected. The code can be translated into an executable program but it probably doesn't do what you expect.

[`strtok` is a destructive function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok). It changes the input string to replace the delimiter, `'.'` in this case, with a null terminator. This means the program will try to turn `"test.lang"` into `"test\0lang"` so that when it returns the pointer to the found token, the token is a c-style string

BUT!

`"test.lang"` is a [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). String literals may be stored in non-writable memory and are always constant arrays of characcters of exactly the right size, including the null terminator. Replacing the `'.'` with `'\0'` invokes undefined behaviour. As stated earlier, the behaviour typically shows up as a bus error on systems that detect and report bus errors.

Solution:

In practice you're probably not interested in parsing a string literal because you'd have to be a idiot to go through all the fuss when you could just hard-code in `"test.c"`. If you're not using constant data `strtok` will perform as expected.

That said, forget about `strtok`. It was a great tool in its time, but that time was the 1970s.

Instead here is one simple way you can do the job in C++ with practically no chance of error.

```cpp
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>
int main() {
    
    std::istringstream stream("test.lang"); // or use any string, including one provided 
                                            // by the user.
    std::string filename;
    if (std::getline(stream, filename, '.'))
    {
        filename += ".c";
    }
    else
    {
        // log error
        return -1;
    }
}
```