# Error: Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)

Tags: c, memory, arguments

I'm learning C programming and I wrote a function and wanted to see how it work.
Here is the snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char s[], int c) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i];
    }
    s[j] = '\0';
    printf("Converted: %s", s);
}

int main() {
    squeeze("abcdefghigk", 'c');
}
```

But when I run it, I received this:
`Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)`

I'm using macbook M1, OS13.4, Clion C23 standard.

Result expected:
`abdefghigk`

But nothing showed up in the terminal, did I make mistakes when pass the arguments?

I have reviewed this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587735/code-138-interrupted-by-signal-10-sigbus-when-executing-c), it looks similiar, but I'm not quite understand the answers, could someone please help explain?

Comment: It's a crash. You get it because you try to modify data that can't be modified. In C all literal strings are essentially *read-only*. You're not allowed to modify a literal string, and any attempt to do so will lead to *undefined behavior*. Use an array for your string instead, if you want to modify it. Or create a new string (array) big enough to hold the new string, and copy the modified data into it. Remember to null-terminate it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Changed to use a string array, solved! Thanks for the explanation. BTW, is the concept stm like immutable type in Python?

Comment: Yes literal strings in C can be seen as immutable. That's why it's recommended to always use `const char *` pointers for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to modify a string literal.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

Use an array for the string:

```
char input[] = "abcdefghigk";
squeeze(input, 'c');
```